# making links clickable while pushing the data into templates

Tags: javascript, html, go

I am taking inputs from user, then adding links for mentioned users and then passing the same in the template

Input: hello @ds
String after adding links -

```
"@<a class="tweet-url username" href="/user/ds" data-screen-name="ds" rel="nofollow">ds</a>"
```

Passing the above string in .Msg (using golang template) :

```
     <div class="panel-body" >
             <p > {{.Msg}} </p>
     </div>
```

Expected outcome is: Hello @ds (with clickable link on @ds) 
However getting everything in text format (same as input).

```
@<a class="tweet-url username" href="/user/ds" data-screen-name="ds" rel="nofollow">ds</a>
```

What am I missing?

---

Got a better solution. First of all I am doing htmlEscape on the input then store it in db, then while presenting adding links followed by using document.write(string) function. With this I dont have to change the template and I dont have to worry about XSS attach. Also I am also avoiding XSS scripts in my database. –

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try wrapping your string (`Msg`) in `template.HTML` to disable the escaping that html/template does.

Example from [the docs](https://golang.org/pkg/html/template/):

> The template
>
> ```
> Hello, {{.}}!
> ```
>
> can be invoked with
>
> ```
> tmpl.Execute(out, template.HTML(`<b>World</b>`))
> ```
>
> to produce
>
> ```
> Hello, <b>World</b>!
> ```
>
> instead of the
>
> ```
> Hello, &lt;b&gt;World&lt;b&gt;!
> ```
>
> that would have been produced if {{.}}
>   was a regular string.

Note that you should do this with great care... make sure that you trust the string you're wrapping in `template.HTML`. This is an easy way to open yourself up to XSS attacks.

Comment: thanks got it. However, how to avoid XSS attack while achieving the same goal. What does twitter or facebook and other websites do? They also make part of tweets and comments clickable.